# configure: error: unrecognized option: `--add-dynamic-module=/usr/local/src/ModSecurity-nginx'

Tags: nginx, mod-security2

I am trying to install  mod security on Ubuntu 20.04 with nginx. when I execute this command:
./configure --with-compat --add-dynamic-module=/usr/local/src/ModSecurity-nginx
I get this error:
configure: error: unrecognized option: `--add-dynamic-module=/usr/local/src/ModSecurity-nginx' Try` ./configure --help' for more information
j'ai suivi ce site web:
https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-modsecurity-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04/

Answer (score 2):

More information will be helpful. Are you in the right directory? You need to run that `./configure ...` at the nginx source directory, not in the connector directory.

If you don't need to compile and just want an updated version, maybe try using the maintained repo from https://modsecurity.digitalwave.hu/